# Отличие модуля от пакета и их взаимодействие с системой

Tags: php, mvc, архитектура, framework

Есть вопрос о архитектуре приложений.

Допустим модуль - это отдельный, независимый от внешнего окружения класс (или набор классов) который реализует определенный функционал.
А пакетом назовем модуль, который имеет зависимости, например от фреймворка.

У меня возник вопрос о том, как система должна взаимодействовать с модулями и пакетами. Допустим контроллеру потребовался определенный модуль - он просто вызывает его класс и работает с ним, потому что модуль самодостаточен и самостоятелен. При использовании он не требует классов фреймворка.

А как реализовывать пакеты? Это должен быть модуль, например, требующий в конструкторе классы фреймворка? И в этом случае пакет не является пакетом, а не модулем, лишь потому что требует определенных классов, которые строго определены при использовании фреймворка, а без фреймворка может быть не понятно что подавать в конструктор?

Чем вообще отличается модуль, от пакета, если вдруг я не правильно понял суть?

p.s. Вопрос о том, как реализовываются модули зависящие от фреймворка, со стороны архитектуры

Comment: В чистом PHP таких понятий как модуль и пакет нет. Что под ними подразумевается в одном из фреймворков, коих как грязи - стоит смотреть в его документации. А если по делу, то взаимодействовать надо через интерфейс.

Comment: @rjhdby я скорее о вопросе в целом. Не касаемо какого-то определенного фреймворка или языка. Но полученные знания я использую при написании своего тестового фреймворка на php, делаю это для того, что бы закрепить архитектурные знания через практику. Сейчас у меня есть типичный MVC фреймворк, где пользователь создает экземпляр ядра, указывает конфиги при его создании, входящие запросы обрабатываются роутером и вызывается требуемый контроллер и формирует представление. Но некоторые модели требуют зависимых от фреймворка классов, а некоторые независимых. Я решил логически разделить такие классы

Comment: Решил поделить их на пакеты и модули. Так, например, если мне потребуется реализация какого-то функционала, я могу найти в сети "модуль" решающий задачу и без проблем прикрутить его к системе. А вот что бы получить пакет - я должен сам его написать, потому что он будет специфически взаимодействовать с системой, требуя определенных фич фреймворка

Comment: Как придумаете - так и будет. Нет какого либо общего для всех определения этих понятий. Единственное, что можно утверждать более менее уверенно - это то, что пакет состоит из модулей. Хотя, я уверен, найдутся те, кто уверен в обратном.

Comment: Наиболее примитивный пример из головы - автозагрузка. Модуль обязан быть самостоятельным компонентом. Значит он не может рассчитывать на автозагрузку классов. Он должен реализовывать либо свою автозагрузку (что для модуля очень плохое решение), либо инклудить файлы вручную. А вот пакет, в моём представлении, имеет полное право рассчитывать на автозагрузку, если она является базовой фичей фреймворка

Comment: Может быть я ошибся в терминологии? Может быть вы подскажите как называть автономные модули и модули с зависимостями? Уверен, для этого уже придуманы ёмкие выражения

Comment: @rjhdby (не знаю увидели ли вы комментарии без упоминания, поэтому упоминаю)